# SVG rotate + scale

Tags: svg

The element should rotate and change its size.
But I can't seem to apply this.

The element should rotate and change its size.
But I can't seem to apply this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="1000px" height="1000px" version="1.1" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xodm="http://www.corel.com/coreldraw/odm/2003">
 <g id="Слой_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>

<polyline id="shape1" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2.36" stroke-miterlimit="22.9256" points="498.93,-1.28 498.93,998.72 -1.07,498.72 998.93,498.72 "/>

<g><g>
  <path id="kol1" fill="#75578C"  fill-rule="nonzero" d="M499.85 462.64c-3.99,0 -5.97,4.89 -3.09,7.66 0.83,0.8 1.93,1.24 3.09,1.24 2.61,0.01 5.11,0.34 7.63,1.04 3.87,1.03 7.03,-3.13 4.97,-6.61 -0.61,-0.99 -1.51,-1.67 -2.64,-1.99 -3.28,-0.9 -6.57,-1.33 -9.96,-1.34zm-26.1 25.9c0.61,-1.41 0.46,-3.02 -0.4,-4.29 -1.97,-2.89 -6.35,-2.49 -7.76,0.72 -1.39,3.15 -2.28,6.29 -2.79,9.69 -0.56,4.13 4.34,6.71 7.42,3.9 0.78,-0.72 1.24,-1.61 1.4,-2.66 0.48,-2.71 1.01,-4.83 2.13,-7.36zm-8.16 -3.57l-2.79 9.69 8.82 1.24 -6.03 -10.93zm24 41.74c-1.51,-0.57 -3.16,-0.3 -4.41,0.71 -2.64,2.16 -1.95,6.41 1.24,7.61 3.2,1.22 6.4,1.96 9.8,2.31 1.65,0.16 3.29,-0.64 4.18,-2.04 1.77,-2.82 -0.02,-6.5 -3.34,-6.83 -2.59,-0.25 -5.04,-0.83 -7.47,-1.76zm37.35 -17.68c-0.42,1.34 -0.22,2.75 0.57,3.9 2.12,3.04 6.73,2.36 7.9,-1.15 1.06,-3.22 1.67,-6.52 1.83,-9.9 0.15,-4.18 -4.94,-6.26 -7.76,-3.18 -0.7,0.78 -1.09,1.73 -1.14,2.78 -0.12,2.59 -0.59,5.09 -1.4,7.55z"/>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                    type="scale"
                    values="1;0.5; 1;0.5; 1"
                     dur="10s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
</g>
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                    type="rotate"
                    from="0 500 500" to="360 500 500"
                    dur="10s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
      
</g>
</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: I think the svg works perfectly. 
https://www.svgviewer.dev/s/TDhErRNl

Comment: I need it to stay in the same place, but it flies to the side.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be centering the path id="kol1" around the point 0,0 and translate it where you need it to be: `transform="translate(500 500)"`

In order to center the kol1 I've changed the starting point of the d attribute. Since the d attribute has only lower case commands (relative commands) this is moving the whole shape.

Also please observe that I've added `additive="sum"` to the second animation. this makes that the second animation will add to the previous one.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="90vh" version="1.1" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xodm="http://www.corel.com/coreldraw/odm/2003">
  <g id="Слой_x0020_1">
    <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer" />

    <polyline id="shape1" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2.36" stroke-miterlimit="22.9256" points="498.93,-1.28 498.93,998.72 -1.07,498.72 998.93,498.72 " />

    <g transform="translate(500 500)">
      <g>
        <path id="kol1" fill="red" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M0.3,-34.36c-3.99,0 -5.97,4.89 -3.09,7.66 0.83,0.8 1.93,1.24 3.09,1.24 2.61,0.01 5.11,0.34 7.63,1.04 3.87,1.03 7.03,-3.13 4.97,-6.61 -0.61,-0.99 -1.51,-1.67 -2.64,-1.99 -3.28,-0.9 -6.57,-1.33 -9.96,-1.34zm-26.1 25.9c0.61,-1.41 0.46,-3.02 -0.4,-4.29 -1.97,-2.89 -6.35,-2.49 -7.76,0.72 -1.39,3.15 -2.28,6.29 -2.79,9.69 -0.56,4.13 4.34,6.71 7.42,3.9 0.78,-0.72 1.24,-1.61 1.4,-2.66 0.48,-2.71 1.01,-4.83 2.13,-7.36zm-8.16 -3.57l-2.79 9.69 8.82 1.24 -6.03 -10.93zm24 41.74c-1.51,-0.57 -3.16,-0.3 -4.41,0.71 -2.64,2.16 -1.95,6.41 1.24,7.61 3.2,1.22 6.4,1.96 9.8,2.31 1.65,0.16 3.29,-0.64 4.18,-2.04 1.77,-2.82 -0.02,-6.5 -3.34,-6.83 -2.59,-0.25 -5.04,-0.83 -7.47,-1.76zm37.35 -17.68c-0.42,1.34 -0.22,2.75 0.57,3.9 2.12,3.04 6.73,2.36 7.9,-1.15 1.06,-3.22 1.67,-6.52 1.83,-9.9 0.15,-4.18 -4.94,-6.26 -7.76,-3.18 -0.7,0.78 -1.09,1.73 -1.14,2.78 -0.12,2.59 -0.59,5.09 -1.4,7.55z" />
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="1;0.5; 1;0.5; 1" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </g>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum" />

    </g>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I move on and I have a problem again, I’m trying to understand, I can’t what to do now.
I want the wheel element to spin, it flies again))

Comment: I changed the code and description of the question and now there is a machine.